# COUNT con un INNER JOIN

Tags: sql

Hola buenas tengo una duda que no acabo de entender como sería en SQL.

Nombre: queue
[image: colas]

Tengo una tabla con las "colas" de tickets que irían ciertos casos.

Y luego tengo otra tabla con los datos de tickets.

Nombre: data
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo podría consultar por SQL cuantos casos por cada "cola" hay en la tabla "data"?

No entiendo muy bien como funciona el INNER JOIN y menos con un COUNT dentro.

Gracias :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que todo, es extraño que la tabla `data` incluya la columna `queue` directamente, lo que debería estar haciendo es tener una columna que referencie el id correspondiente de `queue`, no el nombre.

Dado esto, de todas formas hace sea más "simple" responder tu consulta (pero no lo más correcto). No necesitarías un `JOIN`, lo que simplemente tendrías que hacer es:

```
SELECT queue, COUNT(*) Cantidad
FROM data
GROUP BY queue;
```

Ahora bien, supongamos que necesitas listar las colas independiente de si tiene o no algún caso en la tabla `data`. Ahí necesitarías un `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT q.queue, ISNULL(Cantidad,0) Cantidad
FROM queue q
LEFT JOIN (SELECT queue, COUNT(*) Cantidad
           FROM data
           GROUP BY queue) d
   ON q.queue = d.queue
;
```

Comment: Gracias, me ha funcionado.

Comment: Lo consulté porque en un futuro quiero agregar mas colas y que salgan en un grafico circular que tengo en el proyecto web. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo tu tabla queue es un catalogo no tienes necesidad de hacer un join, lo que puedes hacer es agrupar por QUEUE y contar en tu tabla Data

```
SELECT QUEUE, COUNT(1) FROM Data GROUP BY QUEUE
```

Si quieres que salgan todos los tipos de colas puedes hacer esto:

```
SELECT Q.QUEUE, COUNT(D.QUEUE) FROM QUEUE Q
    LEFT JOIN Data D ON D.QUEUE = Q.QUEUE
GROUP BY Q.QUEUE
```

Comment: Gracias me ayudo